# How to open url in incognito mode using requests (without selenium/playwright)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to scrap following medium article:

Link: [article](https://duregger.medium.com/growth-hacking-25e1db3b79cc)

To get full content of the article It should be opened in incognito mode.

So, when I use selenium/playwright with incognito mode for opening the url. It responds with full article.

But with requests it responds only the half content.

Is there any way to get incognito with Requests?

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
html = requests.get("https://duregger.medium.com/growth-hacking-25e1db3b79cc")
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: AFAIK, the broad term "incognito mode" applies to browsers only. With `requests` and more low-level libraries, you'll need to specify what exactly you mean by "incognito mode": maybe not saving cookies, not saving history, changing user agent etc.

Comment: Yeah thinking about it.
Looking if someone has played around with headers before to get incognito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get full text of the article you have to make request to their GraphQL api:

```py
import json
import requests

api_url = "https://duregger.medium.com/_/graphql"

query = [
    {
        "operationName": "PostViewerEdgeContentQuery",
        "query": "query PostViewerEdgeContentQuery($postId: ID!, $postMeteringOptions: PostMeteringOptions) {\n  post(id: $postId) {\n    ... on Post {\n      id\n      viewerEdge {\n        id\n        fullContent(postMeteringOptions: $postMeteringOptions) {\n          isLockedPreviewOnly\n          validatedShareKey\n          bodyModel {\n            ...PostBody_bodyModel\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment PostBody_bodyModel on RichText {\n  sections {\n    name\n    startIndex\n    textLayout\n    imageLayout\n    backgroundImage {\n      id\n      originalHeight\n      originalWidth\n      __typename\n    }\n    videoLayout\n    backgroundVideo {\n      videoId\n      originalHeight\n      originalWidth\n      previewImageId\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  paragraphs {\n    id\n    ...PostBodySection_paragraph\n    __typename\n  }\n  ...normalizedBodyModel_richText\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment PostBodySection_paragraph on Paragraph {\n  name\n  ...PostBodyParagraph_paragraph\n  __typename\n  id\n}\n\nfragment PostBodyParagraph_paragraph on Paragraph {\n  name\n  type\n  ...ImageParagraph_paragraph\n  ...TextParagraph_paragraph\n  ...IframeParagraph_paragraph\n  ...MixtapeParagraph_paragraph\n  ...CodeBlockParagraph_paragraph\n  __typename\n  id\n}\n\nfragment ImageParagraph_paragraph on Paragraph {\n  href\n  layout\n  metadata {\n    id\n    originalHeight\n    originalWidth\n    focusPercentX\n    focusPercentY\n    alt\n    __typename\n  }\n  ...Markups_paragraph\n  ...ParagraphRefsMapContext_paragraph\n  ...PostAnnotationsMarker_paragraph\n  __typename\n  id\n}\n\nfragment Markups_paragraph on Paragraph {\n  name\n  text\n  hasDropCap\n  dropCapImage {\n    ...MarkupNode_data_dropCapImage\n    __typename\n    id\n  }\n  markups {\n    type\n    start\n    end\n    href\n    anchorType\n    userId\n    linkMetadata {\n      httpStatus\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n  id\n}\n\nfragment MarkupNode_data_dropCapImage on ImageMetadata {\n  ...DropCap_image\n  __typename\n  id\n}\n\nfragment DropCap_image on ImageMetadata {\n  id\n  originalHeight\n  originalWidth\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ParagraphRefsMapContext_paragraph on Paragraph {\n  id\n  name\n  text\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment PostAnnotationsMarker_paragraph on Paragraph {\n  ...PostViewNoteCard_paragraph\n  __typename\n  id\n}\n\nfragment PostViewNoteCard_paragraph on Paragraph {\n  name\n  __typename\n  id\n}\n\nfragment TextParagraph_paragraph on Paragraph {\n  type\n  hasDropCap\n  codeBlockMetadata {\n    mode\n    lang\n    __typename\n  }\n  ...Markups_paragraph\n  ...ParagraphRefsMapContext_paragraph\n  __typename\n  id\n}\n\nfragment IframeParagraph_paragraph on Paragraph {\n  iframe {\n    mediaResource {\n      id\n      iframeSrc\n      iframeHeight\n      iframeWidth\n      title\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  layout\n  ...getEmbedlyCardUrlParams_paragraph\n  ...Markups_paragraph\n  __typename\n  id\n}\n\nfragment getEmbedlyCardUrlParams_paragraph on Paragraph {\n  type\n  iframe {\n    mediaResource {\n      iframeSrc\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n  id\n}\n\nfragment MixtapeParagraph_paragraph on Paragraph {\n  type\n  mixtapeMetadata {\n    href\n    mediaResource {\n      mediumCatalog {\n        id\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  ...GenericMixtapeParagraph_paragraph\n  __typename\n  id\n}\n\nfragment GenericMixtapeParagraph_paragraph on Paragraph {\n  text\n  mixtapeMetadata {\n    href\n    thumbnailImageId\n    __typename\n  }\n  markups {\n    start\n    end\n    type\n    href\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n  id\n}\n\nfragment CodeBlockParagraph_paragraph on Paragraph {\n  codeBlockMetadata {\n    lang\n    mode\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n  id\n}\n\nfragment normalizedBodyModel_richText on RichText {\n  paragraphs {\n    markups {\n      type\n      __typename\n    }\n    codeBlockMetadata {\n      lang\n      mode\n      __typename\n    }\n    ...getParagraphHighlights_paragraph\n    ...getParagraphPrivateNotes_paragraph\n    __typename\n  }\n  sections {\n    startIndex\n    ...getSectionEndIndex_section\n    __typename\n  }\n  ...getParagraphStyles_richText\n  ...getParagraphSpaces_richText\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment getParagraphHighlights_paragraph on Paragraph {\n  name\n  __typename\n  id\n}\n\nfragment getParagraphPrivateNotes_paragraph on Paragraph {\n  name\n  __typename\n  id\n}\n\nfragment getSectionEndIndex_section on Section {\n  startIndex\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment getParagraphStyles_richText on RichText {\n  paragraphs {\n    text\n    type\n    __typename\n  }\n  sections {\n    ...getSectionEndIndex_section\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment getParagraphSpaces_richText on RichText {\n  paragraphs {\n    layout\n    metadata {\n      originalHeight\n      originalWidth\n      id\n      __typename\n    }\n    type\n    ...paragraphExtendsImageGrid_paragraph\n    __typename\n  }\n  ...getSeriesParagraphTopSpacings_richText\n  ...getPostParagraphTopSpacings_richText\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment paragraphExtendsImageGrid_paragraph on Paragraph {\n  layout\n  type\n  __typename\n  id\n}\n\nfragment getSeriesParagraphTopSpacings_richText on RichText {\n  paragraphs {\n    id\n    __typename\n  }\n  sections {\n    startIndex\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment getPostParagraphTopSpacings_richText on RichText {\n  paragraphs {\n    layout\n    text\n    codeBlockMetadata {\n      lang\n      mode\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  sections {\n    startIndex\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n",
        "variables": {
            "postId": "25e1db3b79cc",
            "postMeteringOptions": {"referrer": ""},
        },
    }
]

data = requests.post(api_url, json=query).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

data = data[0]["data"]
for p in data["post"]["viewerEdge"]["fullContent"]["bodyModel"]["paragraphs"]:
    print(p["text"])
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Growth Hacking

integrated marketing for the digitally connected

great growth hacking by — https://beatsmusic.com/

To be honest, I don’t like this term, but it’s a buzzword in today’s tech climate… So. I guess a bit of an explanation is in order.

This concept of “growth hacking” is a recognition that when you focus on understanding your users and how they discover and adopt your products, you can build features that help you acquire and retain more users, rather than just spending marketing dollars.

- an excerpt from What is “Growth Hacking” really? by Josh Elman.

In short it’s integrated marketing for the digitally connected.

Email marketing is a dinosaur, a very hard to kill dinosaur. Companies and businesses can’t ignore the productivity (read “click throughs”) email marketing gives them for their dollar, but also can’t see that it
’s just digitized junk mail. Yes — it works, but it’s costly.

What do I mean? Well, let’s see if I can’t make some sense of this…

...and so on.
```